# When clicking on the RecyclerView item, display a new Activity with information about this item

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I can't solve problem: I have RecyclerView (contacts list). When I click on ilem it should display a new Activity with information about this item. I have code, but I don't understand why it doesn't work. Maybe someone could help me. Thanks in advance.
my adapter class:

```
public class ContactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private List<Contact> contacts;
    private Context context;

    public ContactAdapter(Context context, List<Contact> contacts) {
        this.contacts = contacts;
        this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ContactAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ContactAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Contact contact = contacts.get(position);
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(contact.getImage());
        holder.nameView.setText(contact.getName());
        holder.numberView.setText(contact.getNumber());


        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("image",contact.getImage());
                intent.putExtra("name", contact.getName());
                intent.putExtra("number", contact.getNumber());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return contacts.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        final ImageView imageView;
        final TextView nameView, numberView;

        ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.image);
            nameView = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            numberView = view.findViewById(R.id.number);
        }
    }
}
```

my activity class:

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
        setInitialData();
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.list);
        ContactAdapter contactAdapter = new ContactAdapter(this, contactList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
    }

    private void setInitialData() {

        contactList.add(new Contact(R.drawable.face, "Anna Anna", "358742596814"));
        contactList.add(new Contact(R.drawable.face, "Max Max", "358742596814"));
        contactList.add(new Contact(R.drawable.face, "David David", "358742596814"));
        contactList.add(new Contact(R.drawable.face, "James James", "358742596814"));
        contactList.add(new Contact(R.drawable.face, "Lidia Lidia", "358742596814"));
        contactList.add(new Contact(R.drawable.face, "Alice Alice", "358742596814"));
        contactList.add(new Contact(R.drawable.face, "Mark Mark", "358742596814"));
    }
}
```

and secon activity class:

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView imageView;
    private TextView textName;
    private TextView textNumber;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.secondary_activity);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
        String number = getIntent().getStringExtra("number");
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        textName = findViewById(R.id.textName);
        textNumber = findViewById(R.id.textNumber);
        textNumber.setText(number);
        textName.setText(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well... What does not work exactly? Or what happens instead?

Comment: The code actually looks ok to me. Did you try to debug it or set a breakpoint in onCreate of second activity? Maybe its just a wrong findViewById there... Also, if you make your Contact class serializable or parcelable, you can pass the complete object via intent instead of passing all fields separately.

Comment: So what happens when you click? Does the code in your `onClickListener` get called? Are there exceptions in the logcat? Set breakpoints or add debug logging to your code to see what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not good idea to start other activity in this case. Have a look at at [master - detail fragment](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing)

But if u really need to start SecondActivity, u should modify your code like this:

```java
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ContactAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Contact contact = contacts.get(position);
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(contact.getImage());
        holder.nameView.setText(contact.getName());
        holder.numberView.setText(contact.getNumber());

        //remove holder.itemView.setOnClickListener

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return contacts.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        final ImageView imageView;
        final TextView nameView, numberView;

        ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.image);
            nameView = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            numberView = view.findViewById(R.id.number);
            //Set listener here
            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 final Contact contact = contacts.get(getAdapterPosition());
                 //Your code here
            }
        });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: #Александр Рябов, hello. Could you please explain why  to start other activity in this case is not good idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You never initialize the `context` object in the constructor of the `ContactAdapter` class:

```
//the constructor
public ContactAdapter(Context context, List<Contact> contacts) {
     
    this.contacts = contacts;
    this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context); 

    //add this 
    this.context = context;
}
```

Also when you click the item initialize the intent like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context , SecondActivity.class);
```

Instead of this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), SecondActivity.class);
```

Comment: #Hasan Bou Taam, thank you for advice. But I get the same error.